# How to set state variable by data retrieved from firestore immediately after screen is loaded in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retrieve data from firestore and then set the documentsnapshot data to state variable. I put the code inside `useEffect()`. The state variable, `document` here, is undefined when the screen is loaded and can only be set after I refresh the app. How can the variable be set immediately after the screen is loaded? Below is the code snippet:

```
function ToBeReadDetails({route}){
const [document, setDocument] = useState();
const scrollView = useRef();
const bookRef = firestore().collection('BookStore').doc(Type).collection('Books').doc(id); 

useEffect(()=>{
        bookRef.get().then(doc=>{
            setDocument(doc.data());
        });
        console.log(document); 
    }, []);
return(
        <View>
            <ScrollView
            ref={scrollView}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            contentContainerStyle={{alignItems:"center"}}
            >
                <BookDetails Author={document['Author']} 
                ...
```

Answer (score 3):

In the first render document will always be undefinded. since getting the data from the firestore will take time. it might take 5ms or 500ms depending on various elements, that you cant control, latency ... etc.

The soultion to your problem is having a fix around that, either you have a loading state that shows up a loader til you get the document, og have condentional rendering that only renders when you get the document

like this ex.

`document['Author'] &&  (<BookDetails Author={document['Author']})`

Comment: Thanks. It works after I added loading state

Answer (score 1):

In your render you have to wait for state to change. Like this,

```
return !document ?

    <View>Loading...</View>
    :
    <View>
            <ScrollView
            ref={scrollView}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            contentContainerStyle={{alignItems:"center"}}
            >
                <BookDetails Author={document['Author']} 
            </ScrollView>
    </View>
```